# Laravel validation: With scope gives "No query results for model"

Tags: laravel, validation

Having this model:

```php
class Subject extends BaseEntity implements Treeable
{
    use NodeTrait;
    protected $table = 'subjects';

    protected $rules = [
        'label' => 'max:255',
        'parent_id' => 'exists:subjects,id' // <--
    ];

    protected function getScopeAttributes()
    {
        return [ 'user_id' ];
    }
}
```

Then I create a new instance (parent_id references same table's id, and ID 3 exists):

```php
Subject::create([ 
   'label' => 'foo',
   'parent_id' => 3
])
```

This results in two queries:

`select count(*) as aggregate from subjects where id = 3` (gives the expected result of 1)

`select * from subjects where subjects.user_id is null and subjects.id = 3` (empty result throwing `No query results for model [App\\Subject] 3` exception)

I found out, that the additional `subjects.user_id is null` is added because of the scope, but how can I add this to validation? Either it should be removed or set in any way within the payload on create or dynamically with `auth()->id`. Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, figured it out. It's not about validation specifically, I had to add 'user_id' as parameter before 'parent_id', like so:

```
Subject::create([ 
   'label' => 'foo',
   'user_id' => auth()->id(),
   'parent_id' => 3
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use boot function to automatically create by and updated by.

```
public static function boot() 
{ 
  parent::boot();

// create a event to happen on updating 
  static::updating(function($table) { 
      $table->user_id = Auth::user()->id; 
});

// create a event to happen on saving 
   static::saving(function($table) {
      $table->user_id = Auth::user()->id; 
 }); 

}
```